# Assembly Question

Tags: assembly

Where can I write and compile assembly code ? (I am using windows vista 64 bit). Also is there a Dissasembler I can use?

Regards

Comment: I suggest that you not attempt this.

Comment: Beware legal implications of disassembling someone's code. Part of most EULAs forbids any kind of reverse engineering. Although, there's always the debate of 'if a tree falls in my disassembler does anyone hear it?'

Comment: (1) You should say more about your background and how much you know (or don't know) (2) Write better subjects - I can tell it's an assembly question by the darn "assembly" tag.  (3)  When talking to programmers being precise really helps, for example you probably don't care `where` you write assembly (Hawaii would work) but `how` or `what` tools to use.  (4) Perhaps you should google for "how to ask a question" it sounds silly and insulting, but lots of people can't ask one well (myself included) or don't realize how much it's in their own best interest!

Comment: @TomMD Now THAT was a lesson on asking questions. Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

You can write assembly code in any text editor so long as you have an assembler handy.  For windows, to disassemble code, you can use the disassembly view in VisualStudio or you can use [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/).  Assembly coding depends entirely on the processor architecture.  For x64 assembly, check out [this tutorial](http://www.codegurus.be/codegurus/Programming/assembler&win64_en.htm).

Comment: What Assemblers do you recommend?

Comment: @earn, I would suggest walking through either the tutorial I provided above or here: http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigwin/old/workshops/winasmtut.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can write inline assembly using C/C++ (with the `__asm` keyword).

I would suggest though that you head over to the [MASM32 forum](http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php), they have lots of beginner resources, IDEs, suggestions and tutorials.